# Differentiability of $|y| \ln (1+x)$ about the origin

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Let $f(x,y) = |y| \ln(1+x)$. I want to check its differentiability at the origin.

I find that $f_{x}(0,0)=0=f_y(0,0)$. Next, I write $$\Delta f(0,0) = f(\Delta x, \Delta y) -f(0,0) = |\Delta y| \ln (1+ \Delta x)$$ and equate to $f_{x}(0,0) \Delta x + f_{y}(0,0) \Delta y + h \Delta x + k \Delta y = h \Delta x + k \Delta y$.

So I end up with$$|\Delta y| \ln (1+ \Delta x) = h \Delta x + k \Delta y,$$ and as $\Delta y >0$, I set $h=0 \, k = ln(1+\Delta x)$.

Then, as $\Delta x \to 0$, the function $k$ also goes to $0$. So I think that the function is differentiable. However, Wolfram says that it is not. What am I missing, is it the assumption that $\Delta y >0?$